# Send/write value to websocket server React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket

I am developing an app that I want to use for controlling lights etc. I have implemented Websocket in a React Native app that works (tested that I have connection to my websocket server, `localbus.lp`).
I want to add a `Button` to control some lights, I have testet this with HTML, and that works. But how can I do the same in the `React Native` app?

Example HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="http://192.168.10.11/apps/js/jquery.js.gz"></script>
  <script src="http://192.168.10.11/apps/js/localbus.js.gz"></script>
  <script src="http://192.168.10.11/scada/vis/busdecode.js.gz"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <input type = "text" id= "input-get" placeholder = "Get Value">
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type = "text" id = "input-set" placeholder = "Set Value">
        </div>

    </div>
    


    <button onclick="toggle()">KONTOR</button>
    <script>
        localbus.init('http://192.168.10.11', 'admin:password');


        var toggled = false;
        function toggle(){
            if(!toggled){
                toggled = true;
                localbus.write('1/0/4', true);
                buttontext = PÅ

                return;

            }
            if (toggled) {
                toggled = false;
                localbus.write('1/0/4', false);
                return;
            }
        

            
        }
        

    </script>

<script>
```

Here is my App.js in React Native:
When I run this in my browser it opens a connection to my websocket server `localbus.lp`.
But I am not sure where and how to add a `Button` that do the same as the HTML.

```
export default class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        
        <WS
        
        ref = {ref => {this.ws = ref}}
        url = "ws://admin:password@192.168.10.11/apps/localbus.lp"
        onOpen = {() =>{
          console.log('Open')
          this.ws.send('Hello')
        }}
        onMessage={console.log}
        onError={console.log}
        onClose={console.log}
        reconnect
        />
        <Button>

        </Button>

     

      </View>
    )
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

localbus official don't support React Native, in open source not exist any npm package.
React Native support WebSocket, so you can try realize manual work with localbus using `this.ws.send()` and `this.ws.onmessage`  methods

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. But can you show me in my code how I can manually do it? If it is possible.

Comment: Can you provide link for localbus docs? Or link for source code?